# Why am I getting "Symbol's value as a variable is void: ..." when trying to set lean-rootdir?

Tags: elisp, lean

I downloaded lean for Linux on Ubuntu, extracted it, installed Emacs, installed lean-mode and company-lean via MELPA, it's complaining that the lean-rootdir variable is not set. When I try to set it, I get the error in the title.

Comment: You omitted the most important information from the error message: Which variable is void? Also, which command/value did you use to set `lean-rootdir`?

Answer (score 1):

In the Lean menu, choose Customise lean-mode. Then go down to Lean Executable Name and set it to the full absolute path to your lean executable (I installed Lean 3.4.1 in `/opt`, so for me, I set it to `/opt/lean-3.4.1-linux/bin/lean`). Then click Apply and Save.

This will automagically set Lean Rootdir when you open a `.lean` file.

This way, you avoid having to manually edit your `.emacs` and write elisp, so you won't have this kind of problem. I recommend always setting configuration variables using customize in emacs whenever you can, which is almost always - only a few modes don't support it.